# How can I revoke the activation status of my (personal) Windows 7 dual-boot on my corporate laptop?

Tags: windows-7, windows, windows-activation

I've got a work laptop with the usual corporate ugly SOE on it that only half-suits my purposes.

I got all clever and decided to dual-boot into my work SOE or be able to boot into my own personal install of Win7

I'm about to leave this company so I want to gracefully relinquish the activation somehow.  I'm an MS action pack subscriber, so this isn't a KMS-activated install. I guess that means its a MAK key that has been consumed?

Is there a way, or how can I de-activate this before I have to return the laptop to work?

Comment: I do see a post on this but the proposed solution sounds like it didn't work. http://thehotfix.net/forums/index.php?/topic/25077-deactivate-windows-7/ ...Did you put your own personal install of win7 on a separate partition? You could just reformat it. There should be no need for your existing key on that laptop, and any new windows installation would get an opportunity to put in a new key.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried running "slmgr.vbs /upk", and then "slmgr.vbs /rearm"? I belive that sort of "deactivates" the current computer's association with that key. I could be wrong, though.

Comment: Does that relinquish my license in _the backend_?  I suspect this only works for installs activated off KMS keys...

It seems to be the only option I have.  I'd love to be able to query the available installs count for the MAK key (will check VAMT)